# Hot Reloading is not working with Webpack 2, React hot loader v3 and code splitting

Tags: webpack, react-hot-loader

I'm trying to achieve code splitting and hot reloading with Webpack 2 and React Hot Loader v3. My problem is hot reloading only works **without** code splitting. The other weird part is I can hot reload `Structure` component (see below) but not components in childRoutes. I keep getting

```
[HMR] unexpected require(816) from disposed module 341
```

***See Repro [here](https://github.com/sammkj/rhl-webpack).***

---

Here's how I declare my routes:

```
import { getAsyncInjectors } from './lib/asyncInjectors';
import Structure from './modules/core/components/Structure';

const errorLoading = (err) => {
  console.error('Dynamic page loading failed', err);
};

const loadModule = (cb) => (componentModule) => {
  cb(null, componentModule.default);
};

export default function createRootRoute(store) {
  const {
    injectReducer,
  } = getAsyncInjectors(store);

  return [{
    component: Structure,
    childRoutes: [{
      path: '/',
      getComponents(location, cb) {
        const renderRoute = loadModule(cb);

        Promise.all([
          System.import('./modules/core/components/LaunchPage'),
          System.import('./modules/core/reducers/launch'),
        ]).then(([component, reducer]) => {
          injectReducer('launch', reducer.default);
          renderRoute(component);
        }).catch(errorLoading);
      },
    }, {
      path: '/app',
      getComponents(location, cb) {
        const renderRoute = loadModule(cb);

        Promise.all([
          System.import('./modules/core/components/AppPage'),
          System.import('./modules/core/reducers/app'),
        ]).then(([component, reducer]) => {
          injectReducer('app', reducer.default);
          renderRoute(component);
        }).catch(errorLoading);
      },
    }],
  }];
}
```

Any pointers or guidance would be much appreciated!